# string replace in PHP is not working

Tags: php, database, wampserver, mysql-real-escape-string

I need to insert (for example: "ABC") to my wamp db. I'm using str_replace method for this. Code is as shown below:

```
$currAddr=str_replace(array("'","\"", "&quot;"),"&#39;",htmlspecialchars($_POST["currentadd"]));
```

I'm trying to replace single quotes with a backslash and double quotes with a &#39 to my db because as per my code single & double quotes cant be inserted directly to db.

This code is not working as I expected. I'm not getting what's wrong in this. Any help here...

Comment: If you were to work with prepared statements, this would be so unnecessary..

Comment: OK, the duplicate isn't a "duplicate" at all, but seriously, avoiding SQL injection/preserving SQL syntax **is a solved problem which does not need yet another bad reinvention.** Do it the right way and this question becomes obsolete.

Comment: This code is working when i do in real time. But not working when I do in localhost using wamp server.

Comment: @Paul but that link is for SELECT ... not for INSERT query right... ?!!

Comment: `$currAddr=str_replace('\'', ' ', $_POST["currentadd"]);
       $currAddr=str_replace('"', ' ', $currAddr);`

I did this & I'm getting for double quote.. but not for single quote...